# How to route a landing page to a Spring Boot Application?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-boot

I'm trying to add a landing page to a Spring Application that I created so that when the application initially loads the landing page is the first page that is seen. The issue is, I created the landing page after I created the application and so the application loads a `login/register` page first and I cannot route the landing page to open first. I'm trying to research online where I could possibly complete this task yet I'm lost and would really appreciate some help.

I've included the `WebSecurityConfig` file below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/registration").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll();
        //Disable csrf token as it is not needed for now and is preventing the applciation from running properly
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }  
}
```

Comment: That is what you configured it to do. All requests should be authenticated, hence everything will go to the login page.

Comment: Add success url `.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/success.html", true);`